# How to plot a function of multiple variables in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm trying to figure out a way to make a plot of a function in Matlab that accepts `k` parameters and returns a 3D point. Currently I've got this working for two variables `m` and `n`. How can I expand this process to any number of parameters?

```
K = zeros(360*360, number);
for m = 0:5:359
    for n = 1:5:360
            K(m*360 + n, 1) = cosd(m)+cosd(m+n);
            K(m*360 + n, 2) = sind(m)+sind(m+n);
            K(m*360 + n, 3) = cosd(m)+sind(m+n);
    end
end
K(all(K==0,2),:)=[];

plot3(K(:,1),K(:,2),K(:,3),'.');
end
```

The code you see above is for a similar problem but not exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time you can do this in a vectorized manner by using [`ndgrid`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html).

```
[M, N] = ndgrid(0:5:359, 1:5:360);

X = cosd(M)+cosd(M+N);
Y = sind(M)+sind(M+N);
Z = cosd(M)+sind(M+N);

allZero = (X==0)&(Y==0)&(Z==0); % This ...
X(allZero) = [];                % does not ...
Y(allZero) = [];                % do ...
Z(allZero) = [];                % anything.

plot3(X,Y,Z,'b.');
```

**A little explanation:**
The call `[M, N] = ndgrid(0:5:359, 1:5:360);` generates all combinations, where `M` is an element of `0:5:359` and `N` is an element of `1:5:360`. This will be in the form of two matrices `M` and `N`. If you want you can reshape these matrices to vectors by using `M = M(:); N = N(:);`, but this isn't needed here.
If you were to have yet another variable, you would use: `[M, N, P] = ndgrid(0:5:359, 1:5:360, 10:5:1000)`.

**By the way:** The code part where you delete the entry `[0,0,0]` doesn't do anything here, because this value doesn't appear. I see you only needed it, because you were allocating a lot more memory than you actually needed. Here are two versions of your original code, that are not as good as the `ndgrid` version, but preferable to your original one:

```
m = 0:5:359;
n = 1:5:360;
K = zeros(length(m)*length(n), 3);
for i = 1:length(m)
    for j = 1:length(n)
            nextRow = (i-1)*length(n) + j;
            K(nextRow, 1) = cosd(m(i)) + cosd(m(i)+n(j));
            K(nextRow, 2) = sind(m(i)) + sind(m(i)+n(j));
            K(nextRow, 3) = cosd(m(i)) + sind(m(i)+n(j));
    end
end
```

Or simpler, but a bit slower:

```
K = [];
for m = 0:5:359
    for n = 1:5:360
            K(end+1,1:3) = 0;
            K(end, 1) = cosd(m)+cosd(m+n);
            K(end, 2) = sind(m)+sind(m+n);
            K(end, 3) = cosd(m)+sind(m+n);
    end
end
```